# Hide Mapbox GL features inside of polygon

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, turfjs

I'm using Mapbox GL and Turf.js to mask out the boroughs of New York City on a map using the below code. First I'm getting the bounding box of the areas I want to show, expanding that box with `turf.buffer()` and then using `turf.difference()` to 'cut' out the shape of NYC and fill the positive space left behind with a solid color to create my mask.

Though this mask does indeed hide the features that exist within the 'nyc-mask' layer, some labels happened to extend into the unmasked space. I'm hoping to be able to hide all features that find themselves within the masked polygon. Though this seems problematic since some roads and waterways will exist in both spaces, I'm hoping whatever solution(s) may exist will allow me to filter just text features.

```
nycBounds = turf.bbox(nycFeature)
nycPoly = turf.bboxPolygon(nycBounds)
nycBoundsBuffer = turf.buffer(nycPoly, 20, 'miles')
nycPolyBuffer = turf.buffer(nycPoly, 100, 'miles')
mask = turf.difference(nycPolyBuffer, nycFeature)
map.setMaxBounds(turf.bbox(nycBoundsBuffer))
map.addSource('nyc-mask', {
   'type': 'geojson',
   'data': mask
})
map.addLayer({
   'id': 'nyc-mask',
   'type': 'fill',
      'source': 'nyc-mask',
      'paint': {
         'fill-color': '#addef0'
         'fill-opacity': 0.999
      }
   }
})
```

This has to be possible I just haven't found anything to start moving forward on it...

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble picturing what you're trying to achieve. You just want to hide everything outside NYC? Maybe a simpler way would be to just create a polygon via some other means and overlay it? Can you explain the end result you're looking for a bit more clearly?